# T STRING Error causing me nighamres

Tags: php

```
// SAVE ACCOUNT SETTINGS
if($task == "dosave")
{
$user->user_info['user_div'] = $_POST['user_div'];


// UPDATE DATABASE

$database->database_query("UPDATE se_users SET user_div='{$user->user_info['user_div']};
```

Error received:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in     /home/bennyboy/public_html/user_profile_swap.php on line 26

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is line 26? You are missing something at the end of the last line (`")`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this just at typo here, or is this your original code?

```
$database->database_query("UPDATE se_users SET user_div='{$user->user_info['user_div']};
```

should be:

```
$database->database_query("UPDATE se_users SET user_div='{$user->user_info['user_div']}");
```

I´m guessing you've left out part of the query, can you post it all?

And you need to make sure your value is safe to use in mysql using for example `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

`$database->database_query("UPDATE se_users SET user_div='{$user->user_info['user_div']};`

to this

`$database->database_query('UPDATE se_users SET user_div='.$user->user_info['user_div'].'');`

and try again.